# Is there an easy way to loop through all existing values of an entry field and store them in an array?

Tags: entries

Looking to loop through and filter based on possible values in a text entry field...I have a text field called storeBanner that has 11 possible values (but could have more). Just need a way to go through every entry and create an array with all possible values.

Comment: Can you provide more information? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Haven't tried anything yet. Not sure how best to go about that

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about an array of the *possible* values. But you can get the *actual* values. You can do this with twig's [merge filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/merge.html). First get all the entries:

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('whatever') %}
```

Then loop over the entries and add them to an array:

```
{% set allValues = [] %}

{% for oneEntry in allEntries %}
  {% if oneEntry.storeBanner not in allValues %}
    {% set allValues = allValues | merge([oneEntry.storeBanner]) %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Now `allValues` will be an array of the values

Things to notice:

- You need to set `allValues` outside of the for-loop. Otherwise it will only exist in the scope of the for loop, and not afterwards - ouside it.
- You need to pass an array as the parameter of `merge`. In this case an array with one value: `[oneEntry.storeBanner]`